# Check SQL Server 2008 Filestream status

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream

I'm using the SQL Server 2008 filestream feature in one of my projects, is there a way to check the filestream status (if it's enabled or not) using a query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can certainly check that using the `sp_configure` system stored procedure:

```
exec sp_configure 'filestream access level'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'filestream access level'
```

Should give you something like:

```
name                 minimum    maximum config_value    run_value
filestream access level 0      2         0              0
```

- 0 = FILESTREAM is disabled.
- 1 = only T-SQL access to FILESTREAM data is allowed.
- 2 = T-SQL access and local streaming access is allowed.
- 3 = T-SQL access and local and remote streaming access is allowed.

Reference: https://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/the-truth-behind-filestreameffectivelevel-and-filestreamconfiguredlevel-serverproperty-values/

Comment: Note that the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645956.aspx is actually wrong (it's missing the '3' return value)

Answer (score 21):

The shortest way is

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('FilestreamEffectiveLevel')
```

Which returns just one number: [0, 1, 2, or 3](https://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/the-truth-behind-filestreameffectivelevel-and-filestreamconfiguredlevel-serverproperty-values/).

Note that the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645956.aspx is actually wrong (it's missing the '3' return value).

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!